# Excel VBA filtering loop

Tags: excel, vba

Fairly new to VBA so any guidance or examples i can apply would be greatly appreciated. I have an excel workbook main 2 sheets, i created a userform to edit the equipment list and assign equipment to the workers. As i change the sheet1 A column assignee, i wanted to find the name match the equipment name in sheet2 and add the serial number. Im sorry in advance if this comes off confusing..

Equipment_List

[image: 1]

Personnel

[image: 2]

Tried to loop through Assignee name to match then match equipment if matched add serial number. Got confusing so im starting from scratch using these pics as examples just to get a better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Write the code to Sheet (Equipment_List) module

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Column = 1 And Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                Dim Sht As Worksheet, c As Range, curRng As Range, sEqu As String
                Set Sht = Sheets("Personnel") ' Modify as needed
                ' Locate name
                Set c = Sht.Cells.Find(.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If c Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "Can't find [" & .Value & "] on sheet Personnel"
                Else
                    Set curRng = c.CurrentRegion
                    ' Locate equipment
                    sEqu = .Offset(0, 1).Value
                    Set c = curRng.Columns(1).Find(sEqu, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                    If c Is Nothing Then
                        MsgBox "Can't find [" & sEqu & "] for " & .Value
                    Else
                        Application.EnableEvents = False
                        ' Update serial and qty
                        c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = .Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 2).Value
                        Application.EnableEvents = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```